# How can I add/modify the hash at the current location with a `react-router` `Link`?

Tags: javascript, hash, reactjs, react-router

I want to create `Link`s that modify the hash without changing the pathname, like an ` does. E.g.:

`mysite.com/page` `--link navigate-->` `mysite.com/page#foo`

According to [the docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#to), I should just write:

`<Link to="foo">`

But this acts like `<a href="/#foo">`; it wipes out the path and then applies the hash.

How can I use `Link` to modify the hash at the current URL?

(Note: I *suppose* I could use manually parse `window.location` at `render`-time and prepend that to my `<Link to=`. But that sounds silly.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, missed the part of the docs that says:

> (relative paths are not supported)

Therefore, I guess the answer is something like:

`<Link to={ this.props.location.pathname + "#foo" }>`

Given that the current component has access to [`history.location`](https://github.com/mjackson/history/blob/master/docs/Location.md). In my case, I can pass it in from the parent component, so this works.

`¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Open to any better answers if they exist...

Comment: Relative paths are in-process [here](https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-router-relative-links) and, if that WIP works out, [should be brought into the `react-router` core](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2172).